# Nginx : Unable to load static resources in one codeigniter instance

Tags: php, docker, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

I am running 2 CodeIgniter instances (admin+public) in Docker+Nginx+Php.

When I open the admin website on my browser, the file `/admin/application/logs/log-2023-01-23.php` shows me an error log :

```
ERROR - 2023-01-23 06:27:00 --> 404 Page Not Found: Resources/fonts
ERROR - 2023-01-23 06:27:00 --> 404 Page Not Found: Resources/css
ERROR - 2023-01-23 06:27:04 --> 404 Page Not Found: Faviconico/index
```

## My questions :

1. Why are all folders and subfolders in `/admin/resources` not recognised ?
2. Is there a way to have 2 subdomains `admin.domain.com` and `public.domain.com` serving the folder `admin` and `public` ?

The tree is like this :

```
-admin
--application
--resources 
--system
--*index.php
-public
--application
--resources
--system
-sql
-*docker-compose
-*Dockerfile
-*site.conf
```

This is how the docker-compose.yml file looks like

```
version: '3'
services:

  nginxall:
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/public
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks: 
      codeigniter_net:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
  php:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./public:/public
      - ./admin:/admin
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      codeigniter_net:

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./sql/a3inf4qq_kilifair.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/a3inf4qq_kilifair.sql
    networks:
      codeigniter_net:
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    env_file:
      - .env

networks:
  codeigniter_net:
```

This is how the site.conf looks like

```
server {
  server_name admin-site.com ;
  listen 80;
  index index.php index.html;
  root /admin;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   # set client body size#
   client_max_body_size 8M;

  location / {
      try_files $uri /index.php?$args ;
      proxy_pass  http://admin-site.com:82;
      
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /admin$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }

  location ~* \.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|ico|css|js|pdf|zip|htm|html|docx?|xlsx?|pptx?|txt|wav|swf|avi|mp\d)$ {
       access_log off;
       log_not_found off;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/$uri /index.php?$args ;
       expires 1w;
   }

 
}

server {
  server_name public-site.com ;
  listen 80 ;
  index index.php index.html;
  root /public;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   # set client body size#
   client_max_body_size 8M;

  location / {
      try_files $uri /index.php?$args ;
      proxy_pass  http://public-site.com:81;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /public$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }

  location ~* \.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|ico|css|js|pdf|zip|htm|html|docx?|xlsx?|pptx?|txt|wav|swf|avi|mp\d)$ {
       access_log off;
       log_not_found off;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /public/$uri /index.php?$args ;
       expires 1w;
   }


}
```

Comment: You are presumably accessing your "admin website" via the host `admin-site.com`? But if you are then requesting the URL `/admin/application/logs/log-2023-01-23.php`, does that not imply you have the directory structure `/admin/admin/application/....`? #2 The same way you have configured `admin-site.com` and `public-site.com`? Or is this not actually working?

Comment: I am not requesting the url `/admin/application/logs/log-2023-01-23.php` 

I am just accessing a file located at `/admin/application/logs/log-2023-01-23.php` to see the error logs of my codeigniter instance.

Comment: So, what is the URL you are requesting? "Page Not Found: Resources/fonts" - In your directory tree, "resources" is all lowercase? And why are you getting a 404 for what looks like a directory, rather than a file?

Comment: I am requesting www.admin-site.com. 
The webpage shoes no static resources ( no images, no js, no css )

Yes, `resources ` folder is in lower case and the log shows the error with `Resources` in upper case. I don't know why it does this.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with my docker compose nginx container

I forgot to add the folder `admin` in `nginx.volumes`

```
nginxall:
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./admin:/admin
      - ./public:/public
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks: 
      codeigniter_net:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
```